# Alt attribute inserted as empty

Tags: media, entities

When coding my formatter, I give user an option to provide alt, title and classes attributes for an image. All render beautifully, except for the alt title, which is output as flag-type, empty "alt" attribute (meaning: no equal sign or quotes), regardless of what I try to insert there.

Could the Media module be the reason - such as overriding the alt value with some hooks? If not, any ideas on what could be causing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media module is almost certainly the reason.

There are patches in both http://drupal.org/node/1307054 and http://drupal.org/node/1343022 that you may find useful.

Comment: Yes, the module is undergoing some huge rewrite, hope they'll get it fix. Thanks - it's good to hear a confirmation.